# Text format disappears after moving Matrix field in IE9

Tags: matrix, text-formatting

We are using Matrix version 2.5.10 (Expression Engine v2.5.5) and, when the field is moved up or down, all the formatting in the text disappears (happens only in the IE versions 9 or earlier). Any ideas?